# Best practices around the usage of "private static final String" variables in singeltons

Tags: java, spring

In Singletons, what are the disadvantages and advantages of using

```
private static final String QUERY = "some valid query";
```

over

```
private final String QUERY = "some valid query";
```

Comment: ignore Spring. If you created multiple instances of this class, does it make sense for each one to have a different value for QUERY?  If not, then make it static.

Comment: This doesn't coming from Spring it is coming from Java actually. You can look java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: What has spring got to do with this? The ideas behind the use of constants is the same whether you use Spring or not.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's true, constants are not Spring related. However, my question is Spring related, mainly on the use of constants and static constants in the context of the Spring framework where Singletons are heavily used. In this case, a combination of private static does not make sense and only leads to the confusion of other developers.

Comment: Whether or not to use of constants, and the use of spring are not really related. The fact that some of the spring managed beans are 'singleton' (within the confines of Spring, because they aren't real singletons), does not mean that you need (or should) stop using constants. Normal programming best practices still apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you have an immutable object.

Declaring `final String s = "foo";` or `static final String s = "foo";` doesn't change much since this is a constant. It will never change.
The common sense tell me to set it `static` to limit the number of instances created. (Note that only one `String` would still be created due to the String Pool)

If you ask for mutable object, this is different. For example, a `List`, declaring it `final` only prevent you to reinitialize the variable later, but doesn't prevent the content to change.

```
private static final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

This will give two list, one that is common to every instances (`static`) and one that is a member of the instance.

```
list1.add("foo");
```

Will add an `String` in the `list1` accessible from any instance where

```
list2.add("foo");
```

Will only add the `String` for one instance.

In that case, declaring it `static` make a difference.

---

Every point for instance member are done based on a variable initialized during the declaration, not in a constructor.

```
private final String s;

public MyClass(String s){
    this.s = s;
}
```

That case is different since this would not be a constant, each instance will use a different `String` value.

Answer (score 0):

With the Spring perspective where most of beans are singletons there is no difference. Another point is that you should write code that is non framework-specific and is followed by best practices. Spring is java, but java is not Spring (I hope that your understood).

Comment: I disagree in regards to writing code that is non framework specific as this defeats the purpose of using a framework, especially in the Spring situation. Initialising beans, autowiring and various annotations associated with the Spring framework

Answer (score 0):

The "static final" approach does a few things.

- Only one field is created that is shared by all instances
- The field is created when the class is loaded
- The field cannot be modified
- A public field can be accessed by other classes without creating an instance

This is a very common approach, and there are places where it is the best alternative, such as creating a Logger instance for a class. As far as String constants.

In your case, String interning would cause the runtime to create only one instance of the String that would be referenced by every instance of the containing class, and, with a singleton, there is only one instance of the container. Therefore, no performance advantage.

Having said that, using constants is considered a best practice.